# How to modify the points of a line so that two parallel lines intersect at some point?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have a set of points describing Line1 and also a set of points describing Line2. Now, these two lines are parallel and I want to modify the slope of either of these two lines so that they intersect at some point in the space.

Line1= [(x1, y1), ...., (xn, yn)]

Line2= [(X1, Y1), ...., (Xn, Yn)]

Is there any way to do this? Thank you. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I would like the slope of the line to be changed by a max of 10°.

Comment: you may replace each point $(x_i, y_i)$ in Line1 with $(y_i, -x_i)$.. this rotates the Line1 
 around origin by $90^{\circ}$

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I don't want too much rotation, probably at max 10 degrees would be better.

Comment: Any line can be described using the formula $y = m \cdot x +c$.  If $m$ is the same for both lines they are parallel and never intersect.  Otherwise they must do if long enough. Change any one of $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$ and $y_2$ and they will intersect somewhere.

Comment: @planet_pluto familiar with rotation matrix?

Comment: To rotate Line1 by an angle $\theta$, try below for each point $(x,y)$$$
\begin{align}
x' &= x\cos \theta - y\sin \theta \\
y' &= x\sin \theta + y\cos \theta \\
\end{align}
$$
where $(x',y')$ is the new point after rotation.

Comment: You may just modify each Y by a value, keeping the proportion to difference in X to any starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Both answers of Warren and ganeshie8 worked.